# Identify a rap song in the begining of a movie called Ink & Steel?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I am watching this movie now on amazon, and at around 5min mark a guy goes into a house party and theres a rap song playing.

Shazaam and google are useless in identifying the song. Anyone here have a clue?

EDIT:  uploaded a clip to youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DT1ddS6g9kQ

Comment: Have you found a link of the extract on youtube? We can't help you if we don't have Amazon movies. Have you checked the end credits?

Comment: @Bebs Its strange the credits don't list the song at all and only list 2 songs total (there are other songs in the movie here and there).  Nothing on youtube either.  Its not a major studio movie, I figure thats why.  But it is one of the current recommended movies on amazon prime.  Will try to record with a phone and post it up.  thx

Comment: If you understand the lyrics, have you tried to type them in google?

Comment: @Bebs yea I get all sorts of strange results, nothing that even resembles the song

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the producers and they informed me the song's title is Fear and Loathing In Long Island. They forwarded my inquiry to the artist and he sent me a link to the song at SoundCloud.com/stonahrob.  I've yet to try the link, but I think this is a definitive answer to the poster's original question.

Comment: Incredible.   You are a genius, didn't think to contact them directly

Comment: @Mark, I'm glad that the users from this community did helped you. For future questions, here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.